# Windows 11 taskbar shows only in black color without using any dark theme or softwares...how to resolve this?

Tags: taskbar, windows-11, colors, themes

My Win 11 taskbar only shows a completely black color. I have used many software to change it but to no avail. Also I did all the recommended settings to fix it but got no result.

How can I resolve this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Start, Settings, Personalization, Color (right side). Choose Mode as Custom, choose Windows Mode as Dark, Choose App mode as Light, and then choose a lighter accent color.  I use medium blue.

Comment: What do you have in *Settings > Personalisation > Colours > Choose your colour*?

Comment: @Nik - have you tried the suggestions?  Have you been using the Registry as a User Tool?